# Vector boundary generation -similar to Image Boundary

Tags: qgis, arcpy, gdal

I want to automate the creation of boundary polygons from vector files. This is not footprint or extent creation ([I already have scripts to do this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16520/how-to-get-the-extent-of-each-polygon-in-a-shapefile)). I want to create a tool similar to the QGIS, Image Boundary plugin which creates a single polygon which describes only the areas which have data. It should work on points/lines and polygons. For the points/lines, I guess it would need to create a buffer and then use that in generating a multipart boundary polygon (so it won't be exact but based on the buffer you set).

The purpose to use the output in a metadata catalogue where when you click on a location you only see a list of all files which have data in that spot and not just that the extent/footprint is within.

I found a tool from a [post here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3674/extract-boundary-from-detailed-layer-in-arcgis-or-qgis) that claims to do this but it is circa 2008 and isn't python based- http://blog.shoutis.org/2008/10/announcement-boundary-generator-v-01.html

An opensource QGIS/GDAL solution would be ideal but arcpy is fine as well.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't the Convex Hull (Minimum Convex Polygon) the tool you need? It is available in QGIS in the "vector" menu.

Comment: Kind of but I don't mind gaps being created within a threshold. I don't see this being possible in any Min Convex polygon tools.